# Domain Controller all FSMO roles, AD,DHCP,DNS 2008r2 backup best practice

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, backup, domain-controller

hello I am looking to back up my 2008 r2 domain controller, we have 1 forest and 2 domain controllers, idomain-1 and idomain-2

idomain-2 is used for failover and idomain-1 replicates to it.

having done some extensive reading it looks like system state is the best backup method for what I am wanting, I am going to create scripts to automate the backup process and archive the system states for a pre-determined number of days.

what it want to knows is the system state backup also going to backup the DNS and DHCP parts of my DC? or do i need to run anything additional to the system state?

Many Thanks
BpdZenith

Comment: Your DCs aren't used for failover. They are both live and able to service requests. The concept of a backup domain controller went away with Windows NT4

Comment: yes apologies I used the wrong word, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DNS is AD integrated, it is backed up through the AD database.
If it isn't AD integrated, you might want to look into backing up your system disk.
Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727048.aspx

As for DHCP, this is included in your system state backup.

Comment: I think its included, I am still new to Active Directory, its all installed on the one server what the best way to find out if its integrated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe if you right-click your DNS server in the dns manager, and in "advanced" you can see if it loads the zone data from active directory.

Comment: yep there it is AD integrated thank you for the help.